# What is the maximum of the product of three numbers whose sum is 3n?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, discrete-mathematics

Let $x,y,z$ be three integers and their sum is $3n,$ where $n$ is a constant integer. How to find the maximum of the value $xyz$?

I have gotten through that let $$f(x,y)=xy(3n-x-y),$$

what would be the next step to find the maximum calculus-ly?

Thanks!

Comment: make the three integers equal

Comment: It might have been algebraically easier to leave the equation unsubstituted and use Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: If $x,y,z$ are supposed to be non-negative you can use the usual AM-GM inequality. Otherwise, if $x,y,z$ are allowed to be negative there is no maximum. Indeed $$\lim_{x,y \to - \infty} xy(3n-x-y)= + \infty$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the well-known inequality
$$
\sqrt[3]{xyz} \leq \dfrac{x+y+z}{3} = n
$$
and the equality is obtained iff $x = y = z$. So the maximum is $n^3$. But if they are not positive, then $xyz$ is unbounded even when the sum $x+y+z = 3n$ is fixed. Just consider the case $x = y < 0$ so $xyz = x^2z = x^2(3n-x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume temporarily $x,y$ real. The function has a stationary point where

$$y(3n-x-y)-xy=x(3n-x-y)-xy=0,$$ or

$$x+y=3n\lor x=y=n\lor x=y=0.$$

The corresponding values of the function are

$$0,n^3,0.$$